# How to use nlargest on multilevel pivot_table in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm summing the values in a pivot table using pandas.

```
dfr = pd.DataFrame({'A':  [1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2], 
                    'B':  [1,2,2,3,1,2,2,2], 
                    'C':  [1,1,1,2,1,1,2,2], 
                    'Val':[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]})
dfr = dfr.pivot_table(values='Val', index=['A', 'B', 'C'], aggfunc=np.sum)
dfr
```

Output:

```
A   B   C   |Val
------------|---
1   1   1   |1
    2   1   |2
    3   2   |1
2   1   1   |1
    2   1   |1
        2   |2
```

The way I need the output is to show the largest in each group A, like this:

```
A   B   C   |Val
------------|---
1   2   1   |2
2   2   2   |2
```

I've googled a bit around and tried using nlargest() in different ways without being able to produce the result I want. Anyone got any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) + [`nlargest`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.nlargest.html) by `level A`:

```
dfr = dfr.pivot_table(values='Val', index=['A', 'B', 'C'], aggfunc=np.sum)
dfr = dfr.groupby(level='A')['Val'].nlargest(1).reset_index(level=0, drop=True).reset_index()
print (dfr)
   A  B  C  Val
0  1  2  1    2
1  2  2  2    2
```

because if use `pivot_table` another levels are lost:

```
dfr = dfr.pivot_table(values='Val', index=['A', 'B', 'C'], aggfunc=np.sum).reset_index()
dfr = dfr.pivot_table(values='Val', index='A', aggfunc=lambda x: x.nlargest(1))
print (dfr)
   Val
A     
1    2
2    2
```

And if use all levels it return nlrgest by all levels (not what you want)

```
dfr = dfr.pivot_table(values='Val', index=['A', 'B', 'C'], aggfunc=np.sum).reset_index()
dfr = dfr.pivot_table(values='Val', index=['A', 'B', 'C'], aggfunc=lambda x: x.nlargest(1))
print (dfr)
       Val
A B C     
1 1 1    1
  2 1    2
  3 2    1
2 1 1    1
  2 1    1
    2    2
```

Comment: Glad can help, nice weekend!